# How to open a URL with Xamarin.Forms on Mac OS

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I have a cross platform Xamarin Forms application for iOS, Android, UWP, and MAC.  The app needs the ability to open a URL in the default browser.  In the past, this was done with

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri(url))
```

Recently, Device.OpenUri has been deprecated and replaced with the Xamarin Essentials NuGet using

```
Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri(url));
```

Using this command causes an exception error on the Mac Version : "This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly".  After researching the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/platform-feature-support), Xamarin Essentials does not support Mac OS.

So how does one open a URL with Xamarin Forms on Mac OS?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(nsUrl);
```

That is the Xamarin.Mac code that can be used with dependency injection.